# operation over groupby object returns single values for all columns of new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been spending the entire day trying to figure this issue out and nothing from Stackoverflow about the topic is making it.

I am making calculations over groupby objects but the output is off. I am assuming that there is something wrong with my use of the apply method but cannot figure out what
Here is my toy dataset to illustrate my issue:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001','001','001','001','001','001','001','001','001',
                              '002','002','002','002','002','002','002','002','002',],
                      'Date': ['2020-01-12', '2019-12-30', '2019-12-01','2019-11-01', '2019-08-04', '2019-08-04', '2019-08-01', '2019-07-20', '2019-06-04',
                               '2020-01-11', '2019-12-12', '2019-12-01','2019-12-01', '2019-09-10', '2019-08-10', '2019-08-01', '2019-06-20', '2019-06-01'],
                      'Quantity' :[4,5,6,8,12,14,16,19,20,           8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
                      })
```

and my code looks like this:

```
today_month = int(time.strftime("%m"))
data1['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(data1['Date'])
data1 = data1[data1.Id.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
data2 = data1.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').resample('M').sum())


forecast = pd.DataFrame()
forecast['Id'] = data1['Id'].unique()
data3 = data2.groupby(level='Id').tail(5)


forecast['trendup'] = data3.apply(lambda x: data3['Quantity'].is_monotonic_increasing).sum()
forecast['trenddown'] = data3.apply(lambda x: data3['Quantity'].is_monotonic_decreasing).sum()

forecast['trend_status'] = np.where(~(forecast['trendup'] | forecast['trenddown']), 'Not_trending', 'trending')
forecast['L0'] = data3.apply(lambda x: data3['Quantity'].mean()).sum()
```

the output is this:

```
    Id  trendup  trenddown  trend_status   L0
0  001        0          0  Not_trending  5.3
1  002        0          0  Not_trending  5.3
```

UPDATE:
the desired output is:

```
    Id  trendup  trenddown  trend_status    L0
0  001     True      False      trending  12.3
1  002    False      False  Not_trending  13.0
```

here is the goal of this piece of code:

the goal is to prepare the data including several products for forecasting method (holts method if trend identified and ES if no trend). 
for this I check for consecutive trend thanks to the is_monotonic function
then I use the output dataframe to gather which item is trending or no in order to decide which model to use.
L0 is the T0 time for the forecast, which correspond to the oldest month in the tailed dataframe.

first of all, I am confused why "is_monotonic" does not return "true or false" but 0 in the output dataframe.
second of all, I don't understand why L0 returns the mean of all the dataset and not for each group of the groupby object.

my python level is pretty limited and I have ran out of things to try to solve this. Any help on this would amazing!

Comment: You seem to have a lot of erroneous method chaining that you don't want. For instance `data3` is no longer a `DataFrame.GroupBy` object becuase you've applied `GroubBy.tail`. Everything else after that is simply a normal operation on an entire DataFrame. Then later you're mistakenly tacking on `.sum()`, likely to cover up the misalignment that occurred when you tried to assign the Series, because now you can assign a single value to the entire column.

Comment: That being said, can you perhaps provide your expected output? I think there's a lot to untangle here, it might be simpler to instead illustrate how to obtain your desired output correctly.

Comment: I just updated my question to provide a desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the results don't seem to be even close:

```py
data1=data1.sort_values("Date", axis=0, ascending=False)
data1["obs"]=data1.groupby("Id").cumcount()

data2=data1.loc[data1["obs"]<5].groupby("Id").apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"trendup": x["Quantity"].is_monotonic_increasing, "trenddown": x["Quantity"].is_monotonic_decreasing, "LO": x["Quantity"].mean()}))

data2["trend_status"]=np.where(np.logical_or(data2["trendup"], data2["trenddown"]), "trending", "Not_trending")
```

Outputs:

```py
     trendup  trenddown   LO trend_status
Id
001     True      False  7.0     trending
002    False       True  6.0     trending
```